# Kinetic.Path using svg data

Tags: javascript, svg, kineticjs

I am new to svg and Kinetic.js. I copied some of the strings as the data string in Kinetic.Path but it won't work. However, if I add it in html, it works. [Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fx242/)

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
        <path d='M 145,225 A 88,75 0 1 1 432,228' />
</svg>
```

Below is my code. Is the svg path data string different in Kinetic.js?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// intial stage and layer
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: "container",
    width: $("#container").width(),
    height: $("#container").height()
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

stage.add(layer);
stage.draw();
drawPath();

function drawPath() {
    var path = new Kinetic.Path({
        x: 240,
        y: 40,
        //data: 'M 100 100 L 200 200 z', // doesn't work
        //data: 'M100,200 C100,100 400,100 400,200', // doesn't work. Copied from http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/paths/cubic02.svg
        //data: 'M100 200 C100 100 400 100 400,200', // doesn't work.
        //data: 'M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z', // works
        //data: 'M 145,225 A 88,75 0 1 1 432,228', // doesn't work. Copied from http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/rfp07r/interactive-svg-examples/arc.html
        //data: 'M 145,225 A 88,75 0 1 1 432,228', // doesn't work. Copied from http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/rfp07r/interactive-svg-examples/arc.html
        fill: 'green',
        draggable: true,
        scale: 2
    });
    layer.add(path);

    layer.draw();
}
```

});

Comment: Keep in mind that you set the x and y of the Path object. This means the path will start at those coordinates. Can you provide a jsFiddle? Also, with "it doesn't work", do you mean it doesn't show anything or do you mean it shows the wrong result?

Comment: @RobinvdA I edited and added a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Fx242/

Comment: Adding Z (close path) at the end seems to work, don't know why it is different from a regular svg path tho... http://jsfiddle.net/RobinvdA/Fx242/2/

Comment: @RobinvdA yeah at lease it displays something. But I don't want to close it to get a semicircle instead of an arc.